# Google App Engine + Scala2.8.0 + Lift 2, all ok, but doesn't work why?

Tags: google-app-engine, scala, lift

I build a lift project with this command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -U \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=net.liftweb \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=lift-archetype-basic \
  -DarchetypeVersion=2.0-scala280-SNAPSHOT \
  -DarchetypeRepository=http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots \
  -DremoteRepositories=http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases \
  -DgroupId=demo.helloworld \
  -DartifactId=helloworld \
  -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

When I run `mvn jetty:run, it works.
Then I create this configuration file (helloworld/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application>MY_APPLICATION-ID</application>
  <version>3</version>
  <system-properties>
    <property name="in.gae.j" value="true" />
  </system-properties>
  <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
  <static-files>
    <exclude path="/**" />
  </static-files>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Then I run this command: `mvn package`
When I run `dev_appserver.sh helloworld/target/helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT`, it works in my browser.
Then, I upload to Google App Engine server with: `appcfg.sh update helloworld/target/helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT` and I get: `Update completed successfully.
Success.`.
But when I go to http://MY_APPLICATION-ID.appspot.com/ I get a 500 server error:

> Error: Server Error The server
>   encountered an error and could not
>   complete your request.
>
> If the problem persists, please report
>   your problem and mention this error
>   message and the query that caused it.

Why?

Comment: Just for your information, I found that stax.net is much friendly with Scala/SBT/Lift development. Just uploading the WAR file SBT created, any everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Login to https://appengine.google.com/ and check out the logs of your application.

In the Main > Logs tab, you can see the requests which generated an error, along with the stack trace. This might be helpful to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I see NullPointerException in log

Answer (score 2):

Which version of **Lift** are you using? Google app engine does not run *all* bytecode, from what I understand. [This article](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/1826) indicates the successful port of a scala app to the app engine bt contains a few pointed sentences:

> David Pollak has verified that most of the Lift framework works on App Engine

and

> Overall, it looks like the scalac compiler produces jars that are so close to Java's that App Engine just doesn't notice or care

Now, this article is from mid-2009, so I would guess that if you are using the *latest* Lift and scala 2.8, there may be problems. I would try asking on the [Lift forums](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb), which are very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading this thread:  [Lift 2.0, Scala 2.8, and AppEngine](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/24b36f157f8ea6d2/7aa8a4d97fda631b)